# Stop searching for GPS location android

Tags: android, gps

My application uses GPS to pinpoint the users position and record/calculate certain data. My issue is with trying to get the GPS to 'turn off' as in stop connecting to the GPS satellites. I have tried calling "lm.removeUpdates(ll);" but the GPS on the device remains active. The reason I want to do this is because of battery life concerns.

Thanks

Comment: I have fixed the problem, if your using a google map with the "setMyLocationEnabled" function then this prevents the GPS from switching off. To turn the gps off you must both remove updates from the location manager "lm.removeUpdates(ll)" and also set the display location on map function to false like this "map.setMyLocationEnabled(false)". This should fix the issue if you are using a similar setup.

Comment: Just came across another issue where leaving the activity and then coming back leads this not to work -_-

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
locationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(GPSLocationListener.this);
```